# looping help, cutting program down

Tags: python, loops

Would anyone be able to help me try and put this so it's a loop or so that the code isn't as long, I have been trying and trying and have been failing :/

```
from collections import defaultdict
scores = defaultdict(list)
def alpha():
  with open('Class X.txt', 'r') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
          student, score = line.split(':')
          scores[student].append(int(score))
      for student, scorelist in sorted(scores.items()):
        print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))
def beta():
      with open('Class Y.txt', 'r') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
          student, score = line.split(':')
          scores[student].append(int(score))
      for student, scorelist in sorted(scores.items()):
        print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))
def charlie():
  with open('Class Z.txt', 'r') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
          student, score = line.split(':')
          scores[student].append(int(score))
      for student, scorelist in sorted(scores.items()):
        print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))
```

Comment: Change your function `(alpha, beta and charlie)`, so that it takes an argument which is file name. Then put all the filenames into a list and call the function inside a simple for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
class Scores(object): 

    def get_scores(file_name):
        scores = defaultdict(list)
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                student, score = line.split(':')
                scores[student].append(int(score))
        return sorted(scores.items())

    def alpha():
        for student, scorelist in self.get_scores('Class X.txt')):
            print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))

    def beta():
        for student, scorelist in self.get_scores('Class Y.txt')):
            print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))

    def charlie():
        for student, scorelist in self.get_scores('Class Z.txt')):
            print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))
```

Comment: This is way overkill for what he is trying to accomplish.  If he is struggling consolidating what he has into a single function then wrapping this in a class that still has separate methods for what should be a single one is probably not the direction he should be headed in.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
scores = defaultdict(list)

def read_scores(scorefile):
  with open(scorefile, 'r') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
          student, score = line.split(':')
          scores[student].append(int(score))
      for student, scorelist in sorted(scores.items()):
        print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))


for scorefile in ['Class X.txt', 'Class Y.txt', 'Class Z.txt']:
    read_scores(scorefile)
```

Esentially, I changed your `alpha` `beta` `charlie` functions into a single function: `read_scores()`.

`read_scores()` takes as an arguement `scorefile`, which in this case is just the name of the text file you want to read... eg: `Class Z.txt`

We then create a loop over the list `['Class X.txt', 'Class Y.txt', 'Class Z.txt']` and pass each one into this new function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
my_folder = 'path/to/your/folder'
if os.path.isdir(my_folder):
    my_files = [file for file in os.listdir(my_folder) if file.endswith('.txt')]

def alpha(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            student, score = line.split(':')
            scores[student].append(int(score))
        for student, scorelist in sorted(scores.items()):
            print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))

for each_file in my_files:
    alpha(each_file)
```